# Node.js FS saving object

Tags: node.js, fs

I received this JSON form client API

{ 
  COD: '100',
  ATD: '838',
  PAG: '246',
  VENC: '2017-01-27 00:00:00', 
}

I saved this JSON in var object, then I try save this variable object like this:

```
fs.writeFile("boleto.txt", object, 'utf8', function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Log salvo");
        }
    });
```

But the result in BOLETO.TXT is this: [object Object]

And I need this:

COD: '100',
  ATD: '838',
  PAG: '246',
  VENC: '2017-01-27 00:00:00'

What I'm doing wrong?

ps.: When i call console.log(object) the log is correct.

Comment: JSON.stringify it. Files are just a bunch of bytes - basically a big string. Even binary files. They can't store objects. You need to serialize your object just like what you need to do to send objects across the network. There are several serialization options: xml, asn1, bencoding (torrent files) but in js the easiest way is to simply output JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stringify your JSON first.

```
fs.writeFile("boleto.txt", JSON.stringify(object, null, 2), 'utf8', function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("Log salvo");
    }
});
```

`JSON.stringify(object, null, 2)` allows you to skip lines between your key/values, *i.e.* having a more readable JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This will work JSON.stringify, JSON.stringify converts json object into a string that can be writable in text file instead of [object object]
fs.writeFile("boleto.txt", JSON.stringify(object), 'utf8', function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Log salvo");
        }
    });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.